# What do つれて and いくと mean here?

Tags: words, meaning

> ある日、アリババがロバをつれて森へいくと、たくさんの馬の足音が聞こえてきました。

Can anyone explain to me what つれて and いくと mean in this sentence, I'm having a hard time understanding..

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to look up the two words in any dictionary (e.g. http://jisho.org/)?

Comment: Do you know how conditional works in Japanese? (More than a conditional here と would be translated by "when".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

つれて is just the て-form of the verb [連{つ}れる](http://beta.jisho.org/search/tsureru) whose meanning is "to lead (people)", "to take people (from one place) to another one".

And, いくと is the verb 行{い}く + the と particle. In this case と means "when".

If you still can figure out the meaning of your sentence, there is a translation in a spoiler.

> Therefore, your sentence (ある日、アリババがロバをつれて森へいくと、たくさんの馬の足音が聞こえてきました。) translates into:
>  Once, Alibaba led the donkeys, when they came close to the forest, a great sound of hooves could be heard.

Comment: I would have preferred to see what OP made of the sentence after looking up a couple of words in a dictionary. Anyway, ロバ is not "robber" here, but rather [this](https://goo.gl/W5COC5). Don't let Rikaichan and the Forty Japanese Browser Extensions fool you.

Comment: @Earthliŋ, I hid the translation. Thanks for pointing out my mistake on ロバ. The resemblance with the pronunciation of ロバ/robber misled me.

Comment: hah thaks, i taught it said "robber" so the sentence didn't make sense at all. Didn't know roba means donkey as well. Thanks for your help.